# Combining insertion/deletion operations in Levenshtein distance

Tags: algorithms, edit-distance

Considering the definition below (with $d$ as distance, $w$ as operation weight/cost and $m$, $n$ being the string lengths), the operations $del$ and $ins$ seem to represent pretty much same thing given equal weights (deletion in one string is the same as insertion in the other, and vice versa).

\begin{aligned}d_{i0}&=\sum _{k=1}^{i}w_{\mathrm {del} }(a_{k}),&&\quad {\text{for}}\;1\leq i\leq m\\d_{0j}&=\sum _{k=1}^{j}w_{\mathrm {ins} }(b_{k}),&&\quad {\text{for}}\;1\leq j\leq n\\d_{ij}&={\begin{cases}d_{i-1,j-1}&{\text{for}}\;a_{i}=b_{j}\\\min {\begin{cases}d_{i-1,j}+w_{\mathrm {del} }(a_{i})\\d_{i,j-1}+w_{\mathrm {ins} }(b_{j})\\d_{i-1,j-1}+w_{\mathrm {sub} }(a_{i},b_{j})\end{cases}}&{\text{for}}\;a_{i}\neq b_{j}\end{cases}}&&\quad {\text{for}}\;1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n.\end{aligned}

So my question is, how can we combine those operations without breaking the symmetry?

Comment: Please clarify what $d_{i,j}$ is, what $w_{del}$ and $w_{ins}$ mean, and what do you mean by combining the operation.

Comment: @RanG. I hope the notation is clear now. And about "combining", we currently have to make 3 recursive calls if $a_i$ and $b_j$ are not the same (one for each operation), and I was wondering whether it could be reduced down to two, by considering those two operations as one.

Comment: The question is still unclear to me. Maybe what you are looking for is computing the [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) which indeed takes only 2 recursive calls.